# How do I print multiple strings based on user input using for loop in C

Tags: c

I am confused on how I should format the for loop. I want to print "Happy Birthday" as many times as the user inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int age;
    int bdays;

    printf("What is your age?");
    scanf("%d", age); 

    for(age = 0; **`age ????`**; age++){
        printf("Happy Birthday\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate over a loop control variable

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    int bdays;

    printf("What is your age?\n");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    for (int i = 0; i < age; i++) {
        printf("Happy Birthday\n");
    }
}
```

And do not forget to use pointer in `scanf()`

Answer (score 0):

you don't know how many times the user will input an age, so instead of a for loop consider a while condition? I will use age 0 as an exit, you can do it in different ways, I doubt you want to print happy birthday every single time so I think you need some sort of condition to meet?

also small nitpick, you want to give scanf the pointer to the variable so it can modify it, so in scanf you want &age instead of age

put the whole thing

```
 while(age!=0){

 printf("What is your age?");
 scanf("%d", &age);

 printf("Happy Birthday\n");

 }

 return 0;
```

this way you can do it over and over again, if you input 0 you can exit the program at any time

edit: seems I misunderstood, I thought you meant as many times as the user gives an input not as many times as the age... so the above answer is correct and I am wrong in that case.

Comment: For instance, if the user puts the age 25, the for loop will print happy birthday 25 times and give the year beside it from "year 1" to "year 25"

Comment: the other answer from vsh gives you that so I guess ignore what I said

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Enter how many time you want to print happy birthday");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("\nHAPPY BIRTHDAY");
}
```